# Is it possible to load Phoenix tables from HDFS?

Tags: apache-phoenix

I am new to Phoenix. Is there any way to load tables to Phoenix from hadoop filesystem ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes...

Phoenix is a wrapper on hBase...
So, you can create a phoenix table pointing to HDFS Data and can use it.

Please let me know if you are facing any specific issue related to that...

Comment: Thanks Darshan for your answer. How do I point Phoenix table to HDFS ? Is it part of the DDL statement ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it straight away. You need to import data into HBase first. There are pre built importers (CSV format):
https://phoenix.apache.org/bulk_dataload.html